# How do you get rid of repeating numbers in a Java array?

Tags: java, arrays

Suppose in an array, there is the numbers {1,1,1,1,1,5}
How do I write a program that does not specifically relate to the numbers(ex. no printing {1,5}) that gets rid of all the repeating numbers in this array?

In other words, if the problem was {a,b,c,d,e} and I without me knowing the numbers inside, how do I write a program in Java that gets rid of all the repeating digits?(the example on the very top's answer would be {1,5})

Comment: Convert it to a [set](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Set.html).

Comment: Or use an IntStream and its distinct() method.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to keep only unique element you can use a set.

```java
// Generic function to convert list to set 
    public static <T> Set<T> convertListToSet(List<T> list) 
    { 
        // create a set from the List 
        return list.stream().collect(Collectors.toSet()); 
    } 

    public static void main(String args[]) 
    { 

        // Create a stream of integers 
        List<String> list = Arrays.asList("GeeksForGeeks", 
                                          "Geeks", 
                                          "forGeeks", 
                                          "A computer portal", 
                                          "for", 
                                          "Geeks"); 

        // Print the List 
        System.out.println("List: " + list); 

        // Convert List to stream 
        Set<String> set = convertListToSet(list); 

        // Print the Set 
        System.out.println("Set from List: " + set); 
    }
```

the example is taken from [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/convert-list-to-set-in-java/).
If you need it to be a list you can convert it back with:

```java
List<String> aList = new ArrayList<String>(set);
```

Comment: The OP is asking about a Java array of numbers, not a List of objects. And you can just do `new HashSet<>(list)`. No need to use a Stream.

Comment: @JBNizet this is one of the example that I found, there are many ways to do it. I added a link that has more options

Comment: If there are many ways to do it, why not answer with one of them, instead of answering with a way to do something else?

Comment: @JBNizet there are many ways to convert a List to a Set, the back conversion can be done with 1 line as showed above

Comment: But the array doesn't want to concert a List of objects to a Set. She wants to remove duplicates from an *array* or *numbers*.